# My data (dates) is not updating in Barchart in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have created a project timeline template according to my need. It is working fine with existing data. But when I copy more data into it, my data is not updating in Bar-chart.

- I have trying for some solution but, my bar chart updates when I double click on all related cell or in other words when data comes on right side of the cell, then immediately It gets updated.for example in the given image. From B5 to B13 Dates are in left side of cells. And these dates are not updated in chart as shown by arrow. When I will double click on cell (date) it will come on right side and will get updated.AS shown in other image.

[image: WHEN DATES ARE ON LEFT HAND SIDE]

[image: WHEN DATES ARE ON RIGHT SIDE, AND CHART IS UPDATED IMMEDIATELY]

How can i make my chart up to date when I paste new data in it?

Comment: so please show us your solution so we can figure out where issue may be

Comment: sorry from incomplete question. Please have a look again.

Comment: issue will probably in datetype of data which you paste. You paste some data (you made it via macro, manualy?) and they are in original format datetype (string probably). And when you click cell to edit and then confirm, excel will recognize format and change it to datetime.

Comment: The data is exported from a software. this pictures are just used as example. Thanks for your answer. You are right. Is there is any possible way to make excel automatically recognize data immediately after pasting???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i made a bit testing and your issue will be caused because of cell type format. For cells, to which you will copy data, change their datetype to `Date`.

If you specify cell format explicitly, excel wont try to quest data type of what are you pasting into and chart cant recognize this as valid datetime format, so it shows nothing. This is also why data are aligned to left (as normal text) and not to right as datetime. I dont think there is anymore to explain, but if you miss something, dont be shy to ask.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the possible solution for this problem.

`Private Sub text_to_date_Click()

Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("B2:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        c.Value = Datevalue(c.Value)
    Next c

End Sub`

But, I have runtime error (Type error). In the given code. Please help where I am doing this wrong.